# PHP $_GET with Ajax/Jquery Request

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to set a variable $id=$_GET["categoryID"]. I cannot get it to work. I believe it has to do with the the Ajax request. But I don't know how I have to format it so that it will work in conjunction with that request. I need the variable for a mysql query. Any help is greatly appreciated. This is over my head and have been struggling with it for days. I have tried both GET and POST. Thanks.

I have distilled the page down to this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test $_GET</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {

        $id = $_GET["categoryID"];
        //$id=3; 
        }
?>
  print_r($_GET) = <?php print_r($_GET); ?>
  <br />
  print_r($id) = <?php print_r($id); ?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the resulting page....

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test $_GET</title>
    </head>
    <body>
          print_r($_GET) = Array
(
    [categoryID] => 1001
)
      <br />
      print_r($id) =  
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the whole page....

```
<?php
if (@$_REQUEST['ajax']) {
    $link = $nm33;
    if ($link == false)
        trigger_error('Connect failed - ' . mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
    $connected = mysql_select_db('nm', $link);
    if ($connected) {

    //How do I set $id = $_GET["categoryID"] It fails to set the variable.

        $id =$_GET["categoryID"];
    //  $id=1;
    // It will work as $id=1    

        $results = mysql_query('select * from selectMenu where categoryID= \'' . $id . '\' AND category="' . strtolower(mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_REQUEST['category']))) . '"');

    //////////  


        $json = array();
        while (is_resource($results) && $row = mysql_fetch_object($results)) {
            //$json[] = '{"id" : "' . $row->id . '", "label" : "' . $row->label . '"}';
            $json[] = '"' . $row->label . '"';
        }
        echo '[' . implode(',', $json) . ']';
        die(); // filthy exit, but does fine for our example.
    } else {
        user_error("Failed to select the database");
    }
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/select-chain.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    $(function () {
        var cat = $('#categorySelect');
        var el = $('#elementSelect');
        var attr = $('#attributeSelect');

        el.selectChain({
            target: attr,
            url: 'select-menu.php',
            data: { ajax: true, anotherval: "anotherAction" }            
        });        

        // note that we're assigning in reverse order
        // to allow the chaining change trigger to work
        cat.selectChain({
            target: el,
            url: 'select-menu.php',
            data: { ajax: true }
        }).trigger('change');

    });
    //-->
    </script>
<link href="selectMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<form action="performance-models.php" method="get">
  <select name="category" class="dropdown" id="categorySelect">
    <option selected="selected">Select Your Vehicle</option>
    <?php do { ?>
    <option> <?php echo $row_rsMake['make']; ?></option>
    <?php } while ($row_rsMake = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsMake)); ?>
  </select>
  <select name="model" class="dropdown" id="elementSelect">
    <option selected="selected">Select Model</option>
    <option>[none selected]</option>
  </select>
  <select name="appYear" class="dropdown" id="attributeSelect" >
    <option selected="selected"> </option>
    <option>[none selected]</option>
  </select>
  <input  type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
<p><br />
  <br />
  print_r($_GET) = <?php print_r($_GET); ?> <br />
  print_r($_REQUEST) = <?php print_r($_REQUEST); ?><br />
  echo $_REQUEST['categoryID']  <?php  echo $_REQUEST['categoryID'];?>
</p>
```

Here is select-chain.js

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.selectChain = function (options) {
        var defaults = {
            key: "id",
            value: "label"
        };

                var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        if (!(settings.target instanceof $)) settings.target = $(settings.target);

        return this.each(function () {
            var $$ = $(this);

            $$.change(function () {
                var data = null;
                if (typeof settings.data == 'string') {
                    data = settings.data + '&' + this.name + '=' + $$.val();
                } else if (typeof settings.data == 'object') {
                    data = settings.data;
                    data['category'] = $$.val();
                    data['model'] = $$.val();
                    data['year'] = $$.val();
                }

                settings.target.empty();

                $.ajax({
                    url: settings.url,
                    data: data,
                    type: (settings.type || 'get'),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (j) {
                        var options = [], i = 0, o = null;

                        for (i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                            // required to get around IE bug (http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B276228)
                            o = document.createElement("OPTION");
                            o.value = typeof j[i] == 'object' ? j[i][settings.key] : j[i];
                            o.text = typeof j[i] == 'object' ? j[i][settings.value] : j[i];
                            settings.target.get(0).options[i] = o;
                        }

            // hand control back to browser for a moment
            setTimeout(function () {
                settings.target
                                .find('option:first')
                                .attr('selected', 'selected')
                                .parent('select')
                                .trigger('change');
            }, 0);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, desc, er) {
                        // add whatever debug you want here.
            alert("an error occurred here");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Where's the AJAX request then?

Comment: Without the AJAX request there is little we can do to help.

Comment: It won't work with this... if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {. I assume there is a way to use the $_GET to set the variable $id?

Comment: i read somewhere that using the HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header wasn't of any use if you are worried about security - my word, try to avoid it. As far as the question is concerned, what does the page output on manually going to the exposed url? i.e. what's the result on going to  `www.host/page?categoryID=3' from the browser?

Comment: Ok, want to say thanks, but I don't get it. 

I just need to pass the $_GET URL request to a variable $id to use it in the query for the initial select menu. 

I just don't understand all this. Everything works great if I set $id = 3. It is way to complicated to just pass mydomain.com/selectModels.php?categoryID=3. I do this everyday with PHP. 

I have spent two days trying to solve something I obviously don't understand.  I guess my choice is going to be to stop and start at the beginning to learn Ajax/Jquery.

Anyway, thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 3):

A `$_GET` parameter is passed in the URL so for this;

> http://www.google.com/?q=search

The parameter `$_GET['q']` would be equal to `'search'`

So when you perform your AJAX request you need to specify the parameters in the URL.

**EDIT**:

Try getting rid of your `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` statements. The request is probably safe enough without those kind of checks. Just simplify it to:

```
if ( isset( $_GET["categoryID"] ) ) {
  $id = $_GET["categoryID"];
}
```

Comment: yes. www.mydomain.com/testGET.php?categoryID=3 is what I have be using and it doesn't work

Comment: Ok, want to say thanks, but I don't get it. 

I just need to pass the $_GET URL request to a variable $id to use it in the query for the initial select menu. 

I just don't understand all this. Everything works great if I set $id = 3. It is way to complicated to just pass mydomain.com/selectModels.php?categoryID=3. I do this everyday with PHP. 

I have spent two days trying to solve something I obviously don't understand.  I guess my choice is going to be to stop and start at the beginning to learn Ajax/Jquery.

Anyway, thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Comment: @John do I understand you make a AJAX call without using AJAX?

Comment: @John I think that might be a good idea. You seem to be confused about JavaScript, since I can't see an AJAX request being made anywhere in your page.

Comment: http://remysharp.com/2007/09/18/auto-populate-multiple-select-boxes/comment-page-3/#allcomments

I wanted to set the value in the first menu according to the user making a choice on the previous page.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
```

You can just use:

```
$id = isset($_GET["categoryID"]) ? intval($_GET["categoryID"]) : 0;
```

Which is the same as (but shorter...):

```
if (isset($_GET["categoryID"]))
{
  $id =  intval($_GET["categoryID"]);
}
else
{
  $id =  0;
}
```

If you want to check if a request was made via ajax, you would have to rewrite your script as the whole `header` section would not be needed. Instead you could call this script from your page, set a variable in the page itself and if that variable is not set in the script, it's an ajax call. Obviously this is just a simple example.

**Edit:** The plugin does not mention what the default type of the request is, but that could very well be `POST` so you could try to add `type: "post"` to the options of `selectChain`.

And to make sure that your response is well-formed json (when you get there...) I would also recommend you use `json_encode`, so:

```
    echo json_encode($json);
    die(); // filthy exit, but does fine for our example.
```

**Edit 2:** I just noticed another problem: Nowhere is the `categoryID` being added to the data section in the ajax:

- You are requesting / posting to (???) : `select-menu.php` (notice, no query string!)
- The data you are sending is: `{ ajax: true, anotherval: "anotherAction" }` or `{ ajax: true}`

So there is no way that `categoryID` is ever going to show up in `select-menu.php`.

The most logical thing to do, would be to add the selected category to the data section:

```
data: { "ajax": true, "anotherval": "anotherAction", "categoryID": cat }
```

and:

```
data: { "ajax": true, "categoryID": cat }
```

Comment: Probably best to not introduce ternary operators to a complete beginner.

Comment: Ok, want to say thanks, but I don't get it. 

I just need to pass the $_GET URL request to a variable $id to use it in the query for the initial select menu. 

I just don't understand all this. Everything works great if I set $id = 3. It is way to complicated to just pass mydomain.com/selectModels.php?categoryID=3. I do this everyday with PHP. 

I have spent two days trying to solve something I obviously don't understand.  I guess my choice is going to be to stop and start at the beginning to learn Ajax/Jquery.

Anyway, thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Comment: @John It should be that simple using jQuery ajax or one of its related functions. What complicates it is that you are using an plugin (`selectChain`) where to me it seems you could easily solve this with just jquery. Like I said, perhaps the plugin does not use `GET` but uses `POST`.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can use [`jQuery.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or add a `type='GET'` parameter to [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Some example:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'your-page.php',
        type : 'GET', 
        data : {
            'paramName' => 'paramValue',
            'foo' => 'bar'
        },
        success : function(data) {
             // do something in the callback function
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: How do I use this in page I posted?

Comment: @John this is the jQuery AJAX request. Edit the data and url and add a success function and replace it by your AJAX request.

Comment: Ok, want to say thanks, but I don't get it. 

I just need to pass the $_GET URL request to a variable $id to use it in the query for the initial select menu. 

I just don't understand all this. Everything works great if I set $id = 3. It is way to complicated to just pass mydomain.com/selectModels.php?categoryID=3. I do this everyday with PHP. 

I have spent two days trying to solve something I obviously don't understand.  I guess my choice is going to be to stop and start at the beginning to learn Ajax/Jquery.

Anyway, thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the value in the [`jQuery.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

```
$.get('yourphppage.php', { categoryID : 1234 }, function(data) { 
    alert(data);
});
```

In your php just echo right back your cateogryId to see if it is working

```
<?php echo $_GET['categorID'] ?>
```